# Grouping ignoring blank fields

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I am having a hard time to identify (and fix) the grouping issue I have with the following query. My data has some Country fields blank and the query is ignoring them, only those with non blank values are converted to rows. I tried removing the country grouping but I get the error "You tried to  execute a query that does not include the specified expression "Country" as part of an aggregate function". This is the query I have in Access:

```
TRANSFORM Count([passed courses].[Course Number])
SELECT [domain].[Account ID], [domain].[Account Name], [passed courses].[Learner Email Address], [passed courses].Category, [passed courses].Country, [passed courses].[Earliest Start_Date], [passed courses].[Latest End_Date]
FROM [Domain Master] AS [domain] INNER JOIN (SELECT d3.ID, d3.[Learner Email Address], d3.[Course Number], d3.[Transcript Status], d3.Domain, c2.Category, [passed levels].Country, [passed levels].[Earliest Start_Date], [passed levels].[Latest End_Date]
    FROM

        (SELECT [completed courses].[Learner Email Address], [completed courses].[Level], [completed courses].Category, [completed courses].[Completed Count], [completed courses].Country, [learner dates].[Earliest Start_Date], [learner dates].[Latest End_Date]
        FROM

            (SELECT [courses taken].[Learner Email Address], [courses taken].[Level], [courses taken].Category, Count([courses taken].ID) AS [Completed Count], [courses taken].Country
            FROM

                (SELECT d1.ID, d1.[Learner Email Address], d1.[Course Number], c1.[Level], c1.Category, d1.[Transcript Status], d1.Country
                FROM [Data] AS d1
                INNER JOIN [Courses] AS c1 ON d1.[Course Number] = c1.[Course Number]
                )
                AS [courses taken]
            WHERE [courses taken].[Transcript Status] = "Completed"
            GROUP BY [courses taken].[Learner Email Address], [courses taken].Level, [courses taken].Category, d1.Country
            )
            AS [completed courses]

            INNER JOIN
            (SELECT d2.[Learner Email Address], d2.Country, Min(d2.Start_Date) AS [Earliest Start_Date], Max(d2.End_Date) AS [Latest End_Date]
            FROM [Data] AS d2
            GROUP BY d2.[Learner Email Address], d2.Country
            ) AS [learner dates]
            ON [completed courses].[Learner Email Address] = [learner dates].[Learner Email Address] AND
            [completed courses].Country = [learner dates].Country
        WHERE

            ([courses taken].Category = 'Sales') AND (
                (([completed courses].Level = 1) AND ([completed courses].[Completed Count] >=5)) OR
                (([completed courses].Level = 2) AND ([completed courses].[Completed Count] >=5)) OR
                (([completed courses].Level = 3) AND ([completed courses].[Completed Count] >=1))
            ) OR

            ([courses taken].Category = 'Purchase') AND (
                (([completed courses].Level = 1) AND ([completed courses].[Completed Count] >=5)) OR
                (([completed courses].Level = 2) AND ([completed courses].[Completed Count] >=4)) OR
                (([completed courses].Level = 3) AND ([completed courses].[Completed Count] >=1))
            )
        )
        AS [passed levels]

        INNER JOIN ([Data] AS d3 INNER JOIN Courses AS c2 ON ((d3.[Course Number] = c2.[Course Number])))
        ON ([passed levels].Level = c2.Level) AND ([passed levels].[Learner Email Address] = d3.[Learner Email Address]) AND ([passed levels].Category = c2.Category)
    )  AS [passed courses] ON [domain].[Partner Domain] = [passed courses].Domain
GROUP BY [domain].[Account ID], [domain].[Account Name], [passed courses].[Learner Email Address], [passed courses].Category, [passed courses].Country, [passed courses].[Earliest Start_Date], [passed courses].[Latest End_Date]
PIVOT [passed courses].[Course Number];
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: By 'blank', do you mean an empty string or a NULL value?

Comment: @AHiggins Thanks for your response. Yes, empty string.

Answer (score 0):

What if you added a case statement into your query where if country = '' then return a unique GUID else return the Country column value and alias the case as Country

[GUID function for access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/607288/is-there-an-access-equivalent-of-the-sql-server-newid-function)

You may need to wrap the whole query as a sub query to group by the Country aliased column though. This isn't tested, just a concept idea as I can't see any other way of grouping a country and ignoring blanks within the same select, or a less you did 2 selects and did a union instead.

Regards

Liam

Comment: Just noticed you want the blank fields grouped the way a normal country is and not each blank treated as a seperate country? The following might actually solve it: ([completed courses].Country = [learner dates].Country or ([completed courses].country = '' and [learner dates].country = '')) it's early morning, so forgive me if ive still got the wrong end of the stick here... Liam